# How to open child windows on same display as cursor in Gnome?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome3, display, window-management

I'm doing a bunch of work in [Pure Data](http://puredata.info/) on Ubuntu 18.04 & Gnome 3.28 with a dual-monitor setup in which the secondary monitor is to the left of the primary. Working in Pure Data involves frequently opening and closing child windows, which in my case are opening on the secondary display regardless of where I open them from or where the cursor is (which is often the primary display). This is interrupting my workflow, as I then need to reposition the new window to the primary display.

Is there a way to configure Gnome to open "child" windows either on the same display as their parent or as the cursor? (This seems to me like it should be default behaviour.)

Comment: I'm having this exact problem too, right down to the second monitor being on the left.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: @skylarIttner unfortunately not. I'm temporarily moved away from this setup so I haven't really been looking.